# Compiler: No fresh generator defined for sort Optional[KVar]

Tags: kframework

I'm compiling using the LLVM backend. It can be compiled using the Java backend, but the LLVM backend throws the following error:
`Compiler: No fresh generator defined for sort Optional[KVar]`

The error highlights the `!M` in `<abs> ... .Map => (!M |-> (T1 -> T2)) ... </abs>`

Comment: Can you provide some more context? What sort do you want `M` to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in K's implementation of substitution that causes fresh constants of sort KVar to only be available on the java backend. You can track the issue here: https://github.com/kframework/k/issues/1186

We will try to have a fix for the issue soon, as it ought to be straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it still possible to get support for the Java backend? I've been having an issue with System Calls for a long time, which was my purpose of switching to the LLVM backend.

Comment: The Java backend is slowly being deprecated. If you need concrete execution you should stay with the LLVM backend. Please try out this branch and see if it fixes your issues: https://github.com/kframework/k/pull/1188.

Comment: Thanks. Are there precompiled platform independent binaries for this?